# My image is getting bigger than screen if I try to scale to fullscreen?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to scale a picture to fullscreen in Pygame

here I'm getting screen info

```
cmd = "wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution,CurrentHorizontalResolution"
size_tuple = tuple(map(int, os.popen(cmd).read().split()[-2::]))
```

and here scaling

```
menu_back_0 = pygame.image.load("menu_back_0.jpg")
menu_back_0 = pygame.transform.scale(menu_back_0, (size_tuple[0], size_tuple[1]))
```

and finally printing

```
window.blit(menu_back_0, (0, 0))
```

But, at last, my image is bigger than screen, what is my mistake and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current size of the display can be get from the `pygame.Surface` object which is associated to the display.
A reference to the currently set display surface can be get with [`pygame.display.get_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html). The size of a `pygame.Surface` can be determined with [`pygame.Surface.get_size()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_size):

```py
display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
display_size = display_surface.get_size()
```

```py
menu_back_0 = pygame.image.load("menu_back_0.jpg")
menu_back_0 = pygame.transform.scale(menu_back_0, display_size)
```